# Mongo driver cannot shown in phpinfo()

Tags: php, mongodb

```
# php -m | grep mongo
mongo


# php -v
PHP 5.4.7 (cli) (built: Sep  8 2013 20:19:53)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Any idea? Thanks

PHP mongo driver version is 1.2.12

Comment: The driver probably isn't loaded.

Comment: I have add `extension=mongo.so` in php.ini

Comment: CLI usually has not the same php.ini as webserver.

Comment: @Pazi Thank you. How can I find the CLI's php.ini?

Comment: phpinfo() will show you the path of the configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps in the below link

[Installing Mongi Driver for PHP](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/)

Also Looks like you are having trouble in  loading the driver by adding the line

```
extension=mongo.so
```

to php configuration

To do that you need to first locate your php.ini files , normally there will be two files one for command line and one for apache .

Off course you can find it in phpinfo() . If you could not find it then

**To know the locations of php configuration**

Just run below command

```
php --ini
```

This command lists all configuration files which are some times not visible in phpinfo()

Hope this helps

**NOTE : -** I assume that you are using Linux or Unix environment and not windows .  I did this guess by looking at the grep command which you have posted in your code :)

Comment: Good references. I forget to restarted the php-fpm after install the mongo driver.